# <table> inside the <li> convert to PDF using itext not working

Tags: java, itextpdf, simplexmlrpcserver

I am using itextpdf(using `SimpleXMLParser` to parse)for converting HTML to PDF. The html contains `<table>` inside the `<li>` tag.

After converted to pdf, the pdf contains only text, but not table contents.

Update: I am using itextpdf-5.1.3.jar

Anyone please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Which version of itext you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce your problem, but the table shows up. This is my HTML file: [table9.html](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/table9.html) and this is my code: [ParseHtmlTable9](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable9)

The result looks like this:
[image]

Granted. It looks somewhat odd, but the table is rendered and a few tweaks to the HTML (maybe add some CSS) should be sufficient to get a good result.

Comment: Note that above is correct, provided the `<table>` element isn't wrapped in a `<div>`. I had a similar problem as outlined in the question, where the output didn't contain any of my table content (or any other content for that matter). With the help of the answer above, and a whole lot of trail-error, I discovered that having a `<div>` in a `<li>` messes things up. Note that divs in list items are perfectly valid html, so I guess it's simply not supported by iText.